# Why if i have more than 1 form in the same page with the same input file ID it is take just the first ID?

Tags: ajax

I have more than form in the same file like

```
<form name="myForm">
<input type="hidden" value="1" id="lastphp">
<a onclick="ajaxFunction()" class="folloo">
</form>
<form name="myForm">
<input type="hidden" value="2" id="lastphp">
<a onclick="ajaxFunction()" class="folloo">
</form>
<form name="myForm">
<input type="hidden" value="3" id="lastphp">
<a onclick="ajaxFunction()" class="folloo">
</form>
<form name="myForm">
<input type="hidden" value="4" id="lastphp">
<a onclick="ajaxFunction()" class="folloo">
</form>
```

but when I click on any link it always take the first ID which is 1??

Comment: Why do you use X forms with the same name ?

Comment: @Michael Laffargue I just gave other names with no luck

Comment: What does ajaxFunction have in it? Can we see that code?

Comment: here is the ajax fuction http://www.codesend.com/view/05a831c9c5c8047f307f34722cc94b0e/

Comment: An ID should be unique to the page.

Comment: @Darkwater23  and here is the php function http://www.codesend.com/view/142c914ea9248fc344617bb8e117eb33/

Comment: how can I do unique id in the php file?

Answer (score 0):

An ID needs to be unique to the page, as it is a key for that element.

Why not change id="lastphp" to class="lastphp" and pass the form to the function?

```
<form name="myForm">
    <input type="hidden" value="1" class="lastphp">
    <a onclick="ajaxFunction(this.parentNode)" class="folloo">Test</a>
</form>
<form name="myForm">
    <input type="hidden" value="2" class="lastphp">
    <a onclick="ajaxFunction(this.parentNode)" class="folloo">Test</a>
</form>
<form name="myForm">
    <input type="hidden" value="3" class="lastphp">
    <a onclick="ajaxFunction(this.parentNode)" class="folloo">Test</a>
</form>
<form name="myForm">
    <input type="hidden" value="4" class="lastphp">
    <a onclick="ajaxFunction(this.parentNode)" class="folloo">Test</a>
</form>
```

And haddle it like this

```
function ajaxFunction(form) {
    var lastphp = form.getElementsByClassName("lastphp")[0].value;
    alert(lastphp);
}
```

This can be alot easier with a framework, like jQuery.